# Retrieve matched properties in Criteria query (like an explanation of the result)

Tags: hibernate

I'm using Hibernate in a project, and I have to search for Objects in the Database by inserting some constraints.
I want the search procedure to return a row containing the id of the Object, some information on childs entities and, most important, something describing why the row is present in the result, for example a list of pair (matched entity, matched property) including matched child.
I already did it in plain sql, and it's tedious. I think i would be able do do it using hibernate hql too, but it sounds like I'm rewriting the same thing, just in a slighty different language. My question is : There's a way do do it cleanly, using criteria, with as least sql query as possible?
I know that the question is very wide so notice that here I'm searching for advices, tips, best practice, not for complete implementations. Something we can elaborate on later to find a good solution...
Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is query by example where you can give hibernate an example of the entities it should look for. maybe you could the compare the results with the example.

```
Example example = Example.create(exampleobj)...; // add configs how to work with the example
Criteria crit = currentSession.createCriteria(Mitarbeiter.class).add(example);
```